# Are there any security issues with setting the WP_INSTALLING constant to true?

Tags: customization, constants

Running Wordpress 4.1 on a CentOS 6.5 instance through VirtualBox as a dev server. When logged in as admin on both ssl and non-ssl sites Wordpress curl requests are taking a long time to run (45+ seconds overall before page loads). This renders my dev site unusable, as you can imagine.

While browsing around I found many people complaining of this extremely slow curl issue and I've discovered that setting the `WP_INSTALLING` constant to true speeds the site up 100%. I imagine it blocks all outgoing requests?

What are the consequences of setting this? I see that it breaks my front-end (admin side works well).

```
define('WP_INSTALLING', true);
```

Or, How can I just disable all outgoing requests? I profiled the page load and it appears that 65% of the hanging is due to curl requests. I just want to disable these external checks.

Comment: Did you try `define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true);`

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. That was exactly what I needed. I didn't know that constant exists. Thanks!

Comment: Telling WordPress that it is installing an update seems an odd way to improve performance, for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I want to credit @wyck for his answer of setting:

```
define( 'WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true );
```

I also just wanted to add that [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Block_External_URL_Requests) and a lot of nice other config options are [nicely documented in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php).